# OS X default listening ports

Tags: macos, security

Is there somewhere I can find a default list of open ports on OSX for various versions, or a particular version?

I would like to know what is on by default so I can see if something should be there or not, and so I can disable what I may consider unnecessary.

I cannot find such a list anywhere, which is odd since such lists are available for Windows and Linux distributions.

Comment: Close everything, and open as required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any "list" available, since it really depends on what software is installed on your Mac.  To find out though, try [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html).  It's a fantastic firewall program for OSX that lets you see who your Mac is talking to, on what port, and allows you to allow/deny whenever you want.

Comment: I am after a default list though, as in freshly bought and no software yet installed aside from what came with the mac.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this question.  Every port that is open and the process that is on that port can be listed.  Verify those processes are valid.

Comment: It also depends on how the mac has been setup.  I'm afraid that you might have a hard time finding such a list.

Comment: talking about a default mac, powered on for the first time.